# convert code to use Linq

Tags: linq, list

I have the following code, I want to use Linq, any possible ??

I have one list of users, and I need generate other list.

any help ? thanks in advance, greetings

```
 SortedList<ClaveUsuarioPersonal, UsuarioRe> users = new SortedList<ClaveUsuarioPersonal, UsuarioRe>();

            if (this.UsuarioRe.UsuarioSar != null)
            {
                foreach (DC.AccesosUsuario var in this.UsuarioRe.UsuarioSar.ListaAccesos)
                {
                    if (var != null && var.Aprobado.Value)
                    {
                        UsuarioRe usuario = UserContextBLL.ObtenerUsuarioRe(var.Login);
                        if(usuario!=null && usuario.UsuarioAire!=null)
                        {
                            if (!usuario.UsuarioAire.Empresa.HasValue)
                            {
                                Log.Trace(Utility.LogCategory, "No existe empresa para el usuario de Aire " + usuario.UsuarioAire.Login);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ClaveUsuarioPersonal clave = new ClaveUsuarioPersonal(Convert.ToInt32(usuario.UsuarioAire.Empresa.Value), usuario.UsuarioAire.Login);

                                users.Add(clave, usuario);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return users;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try installing [Resharper 5.0 Nightly Build](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds).
It has a lot of features to convert for/foreach to linq statements. It might be helpful for those who want to learn LINQ.
More info on these features [here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2009/12/resharper-50-preview-loops-2-linq/).

Edit: Jetbrains released [Resharper 5.0 Beta](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/beta/beta.html) a few days ago. Seems to be more stable than the nightly builds.

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = from u in this.UsuarioRe.UsuarioSar.ListaAccesos
            where (UserContextBLL.ObtenerUsuarioRe(u.Login) != null) 
                && (UserContextBLL.ObtenerUsuarioRe(u.Login).UsuarioAire != null)
                && (UserContextBLL.ObtenerUsuarioRe(u.Login).UsuarioAire.Empressa.HasValue)
            select (new ClaveUsuarioPersonal(Convert.ToInt32(UserContextBLL.ObtenerUsuarioRe(u.Login).UsuarioAire.UsuarioAire.Empresa.Value), UserContextBLL.ObtenerUsuarioRe(u.Login).UsuarioAire.Login));
```

I can't test this because I don't have your classes. Also I'm not sure how to implement the logging feature in the the LINQ expression. It should get you the list though.